# Gulp get sources but ignore certain sub-extensions

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

Is it possible to ignore certain sub extensions when getting files of a certain type? I basically only want to grab the **regular `something.js`** file. **Not** `something.component.js` or `something.test.js`

For example:

```
gulp.src('(!.component.js|.test.js)*.js')
```

I can't seem to find the correct Regex or anything to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try

```
gulp.src(['*.js', '!*.component.js', '!*.test.js']);
```

More info [here](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch)